# Rails 4 custom helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i am trying to create a helper method to display different time formats if a post was created in the last 24hrs.

This is what I did in the posts_helper.rb

```
def recent_post_time
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.created_at.hour < 24
    @post.created_at = @post.created_at.strftime("%R")
  else
    @post.created_at = @post.created_at.strftime("%v")  
  end   
end
```

And Index view

```
 <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= recent_post_timre %>
 <% end %>
```

However I keep getting this error "Couldn't find Post without an ID" any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're iterating over posts and want to display the time for each, yes? If so, you should pass the post into the `recent_post_time` method, eg.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= recent_post_time(post) %>
<% end %>
```

And then adjust your `recent_post_time` method to use the passed in post.

You should also not be trying to assign the value of `created_at`, just output it.

Checking that the hour is < 24 isn't quite what you want either (it's always less than 24 given that there's only 24 hours in a day, so it would always be 0-23) - you want if it was greater than a day ago, so I've changed your code to reflect that.

```
def recent_post_time(post)
  if post.created_at < 1.day.ago
    post.created_at.strftime("%R")
  else
    post.created_at.strftime("%v")  
  end   
end
```

Comment: you might have to be more specific. What are you expecting it to do and what is it not doing? If the error hasn't changed, then the error is unrelated to the problem you have posted. Please post the full logs of the error.

Comment: Sorry it was a fault on my path, thanks for your help. Does rails provide a "today" method i can use instead of using the last 24hrs ?

Comment: This is what i tried to do, it works but is this the right way to accomplish it ? if post.created_at > Date.today

Comment: that will tell you if the post was created today, but that's not what your original post asked for.